# How to get & set global .class level css values in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, global-variables

What I want to do is something like this.

Get the global css value for a class.
Where .myclass references the actual static class rather then an instance that implements the class.

```
var currentmargin = $('.myclass').css('margin');
```

Then display global class css value for user to modify
and then set the changes

```
$('.myclass').css('margin',newValue);
```

from a css like below

```
.myclass {
  margin:10px;
}
```

Is there a right way to do this in JQuery that I am missing or do I need to extend things with a plugin like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/changecss in order to get the job done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confusing the use of Jquery selectors. The following:

```
var currentmargin = $('.myclass').css('margin');
```

Mean: select all elements within HTML document which marked with class named "`myclass`" and then read from attribute 'style' value of css property "`margin`". And I'm afraid there is no way using client side JS to read the global definition for css property value unless you have some element on page which marked with this class.

So I guess the reason why always got undefined is because you do not have any element marked with class "`myclass`".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I modified my question a bit to get at the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery itself doesn't really help in any way here, everything you want to do centers around [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.styleSheets), a basic DOM collection, one jQuery provides no wrappers, etc. around.  The [plugin you linked](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/changecss) is a good approach (since it's that lightweight), or just loop through the collections in `document.styleSheets` just like it does.

Comment: Thanks, so nothing in JQuery directly, that is what I needed to know. Thinking I might extend the plugin to support both get and set.